# Is it correct to use the word "videos" as plural of "video"?

Tags: plural-forms

I.e. in the sentence:

> I'm searching for gardening related **videos**.

or:

> You may download the two **videos** at this link...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking whether "video" is a word that can be made plural, or whether "videos" is the right way to spell the plural of "video"? (The answer to both questions is yes, incidentally.)

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/video_1

Comment: @phenry - I was asking both questions, actually.

Comment: @snailplane - Thanks for the link. The on-line dictionary I saw was missing the information on the plural of the word "video". Thus I asked here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common to use "videos" to describe a plurality of video presentations of some kind, so both of your sentences are correct.  On the other hand, if a station has video in the form of three satellite feeds, it has three video feeds, not three videos.  Video in the sense of video data is a mass or uncountable noun.

Now, your "gardening related" should be "gardening-related" because the two words taken together function as an adjective applying to videos.

Comment: I was sure enough about your "video feeds" example usage, while not on the one I asked. And thanks for the tip about the hyphen. :)

Answer (score -2):

Both the words are okay if used properly .
If you are using for plural nouns then "videos" is Okay and for singular "video" is also good but I would like to suggest you to follow this format only because this is the more preferable format grammatically.